# Referencing CSS from a User Control

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET user control that references some CSS classes. In the **Error List** pane I get the following warning for each CSS reference: **The class or CssClass value is not defined**. Is there any way around this?

Comment: No, there's no way around it that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your user controls. This will trick VS into thinking there is a stylesheet while avoiding at the same time it being included as a duplicate.

```
<% if (false) { %>
    <link href="Content/Css/Styles.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } %>
```